# why am I getting warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST', 'ChangeLog', 'GPL when mysql-python installs successfully

Tags: django, virtualenv, mysql-python

When using pip to install mysql-python in virtualenv on ubuntu, the install goes through successfully but with the following warnings:

warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'

Anyone know why? is it something I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files aren't important for running MySQLdb, but they should be included, and I'll fix this for the next release if possible. (Fixed in the 1.2.4 betas)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as long as it is not a serious problem I don't mind.